# How to ID a control with Windows Spy?

Tags: autohotkey

Newby here...I have my first script running...yeah! But I'd like to read some window controls. I see in the AHK Help for GetControlPos and others:

Can be either ClassNN (the classname and instance number of the control) or the name/text of the control, both of which can be determined via Window Spy.

Duh, I can't find the info in Windows Spy. Can someone point me in the right direction...TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hover over the controls with you mouse. In the "Under mouse" section you will see what can be gathered from the application. In quite a few situations, you will not see more that the colour under the mouse. When the application has named controls, you will then see the ClassNN name/ID.

In short, not all programs have named controls.

You can test with e.g. Notepad and in Notepad use file save. The file save dialog has named controls.

Comment: Now I do feel dumb...I tested three different windows and missed the obvious. Thanks

Comment: Robert,  This is not so obvious, it took me some time to sort it out, and I am still learning every day.